# Honeywell scanner. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit

Tags: android, android-intent, honeywell

I use Honeywell SKD for scan barcodes.
On Android 4.4.1 all work fine, but on 7.7.1 i got error.
I trying to use recommended service intent, but most likely something all the same I am doing wrong.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.honeywell.decoderservice.STARTSERVICE");
serviceIntent.setPackage("com.honeywell.decoderservice");
mDecodeManager = new DecodeManager(this, ScanResultHandler); // this line throws exception
```

My error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: md.avalon.avalontsd, PID: 3288
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{md.avalon.avalontsd/md.avalon.avalontsd.ReceiptActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.honeywell.decoderservice.STARTSERVICE }
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6130)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.honeywell.decoderservice.STARTSERVICE }
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1346)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1455)
                  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1423)
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:636)
                  at com.honeywell.decodemanager.DecodeManager.bindDecoderService(DecodeManager.java:121)
                  at com.honeywell.decodemanager.DecodeManager.<init>(DecodeManager.java:211)
                  at md.avalon.avalontsd.ReceiptActivity.onCreate(ReceiptActivity.java:181)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
```

How to solve the problem? 
Thank you.

Comment: Scarcely. The first two lines I took from there.

Comment: Please note that the line that is throwing the exception does not appear to be using the `Intent` shown in the preceding two lines. Your problem lies inside of `DecodeManager`; if that is from Honeywell, you need to talk to Honeywell about getting a newer version of their SDK.

Comment: Thank you. New version of SDK works perfect.